# What are the stories of creation in hindu scrpitures?

Tags: vedas

There are many stories of creation in our hindu scriptures,the hiryanyagarbha sukta and purusha sukta explains about creation but are there any other stories describe in scriptures like upanishads,vedas brahmanas.

Comment: this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @swami vishwananda what does duplicate question mean?

Comment: question already asked and answered. It will be closed because it is duplicate. Do a search on the website for 'creation'